# $watch is not being hit in Angular's directive when a checkbox's value is changed

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

i have a directive setup like this.

```
angular.module('app')
  .directive('bootstrapCheck', function () {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      require: '?ngModel',
      link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
        $.getScript("../../Scripts/js/checkBoxFunctions.js",  function () {
        });
        scope.$watch(attrs.ngModel, function (newValue, oldValue) {
          //debugger;
        });
      }
    };
  });
```

and it's html looks like

```
<section id="dashboard-view" data-ng-controller="dashboard as vm">
  <input type="checkbox" ng-model="vm.my.bool.prop" ng-checked="vm.my.bool.prop" bootstrap-check>
</section>
```

and property is setup like this

```
var vm = this;
vm.my = {
  bool: {
    prop: true
  }
};
```

it seems like the check-box is bound to the property. but whenever i click the check-box i expect it to hit the debugger but it is not working.

Comment: `bool` is missing a curly bracket

Comment: it was there in the actual code. soory for misunderstanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you don't have `jQuery` loaded on the page so `$.getScript` is throwing an exception due to which `$watch` is never executed.

If you remove that code I am sure `$watch` will work fine.

Demo http://plnkr.co/edit/EB3yoccf1N9TLIAawnRM?p=preview